# How do I change the boot sequence on my computer?

Tags: dual-boot

I have windows Vista and Ubuntu 13.1 on my computer. It keeps trying to default boot to Windows. How do I change this?

Answer (score 1):

I once suffered with a similar problem.  My solution was to install Grub Customizer.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Great tool.